# Radius of convergence of power series and its formal derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(z-z_0)^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, i.e., it converges absolutely on $|z-z_0|<R$ and diverges on $|z-z_0|>R$. Consider the series obtained after formal differentiation $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)c_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n$. I want to show that it has the same radius of convergence $R$.

By Cauchy-Hadamard theorem it is enough to show that $$\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)|c_{n+1}|}.$$

But since $\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)|c_{n+1}|}=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_{n+1}|}$ so we need to show that $$\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_{n+1}|}.$$

I know that this question has been asked couple times but I asked in those posts and no one answered me since topics are outdated.

I would be very thankful for clear explanation!

Comment: Suppose $c_{n_k}$ is a subsequence along which $\lim_k\sqrt[n_k]{|c_{n_k}|}=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$
Then $c_{n_k}$ is also a subsequence of $d_n:=c_{n+1}$ (why?)
In fact $c_{n_k}=d_{n_k-1}$. The rest should be straight forward.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, if you can give the details of the rest that should be great. The details are the most interesting.

Comment: Extended real numbers are very typical, in fact it is widely used in integrating theory for example. Here is a wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) Rudin's principles of Mathematical analysis talk about it (pp 11), Apostol's Analysis also discusses it (pp.14); My soviet era textbooks discuss it also at the beginning. I am sure your book does to.

Comment: Since you are a PhD student in Mathematics, presumably you have studied points topology at some point. So, you can think of the extended real line $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}=\overline{R}=[-\infty,\infty]$ as a two point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, the same way the $[a,b]$, $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, is a two point compactification of the interval $(a,b)$ It turns outs out, that $[0,1]$ for example and $\overline{R}$ are homeomorphic. The space $\overline{R}$ is not a field since $\pm\infty$ has no multiplicative inverse, but its structure is still very useful.

Comment: @ZFR: Really? in your profile it states that you are a PhD student in math. This is something that is very trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Let$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\quad\text{and}\quad b_n=\left(a_{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)/n}=\left(\sqrt[n+1]{|c_{n+1}|}\right)^{(n+1)/n}=\sqrt[n]{|c_{n+1}|}.$$
If we prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n$, then the problem is solved.

Note that this defines $b_n$ using $a_n$, but the process can be reversed (that is, we can define $a_n$ using $b_n$), since$$n>1\implies a_n=(b_{n-1})^{n/(n-1)}.\tag1$$

Let $S=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$. There is a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that$$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=S.\tag2$$But then$$\lim_{k\to\infty}b_{n_k-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n_k})^{n_k/(n_k-1)}=S,$$because we have $(2)$ and also because $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_k}{n_k-1}=1$. So, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n\geqslant S$. But if $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n=S^\star>S$, then the same argument, together with $(1)$, shows that$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\geqslant S^\star>S=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n,$$which is not possible.

Comment: Sorry but I do not think you answered my question. I am interested in how $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{|c_{n+1}|}\right)^{(n+1)/n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$ was obtained. I agree that $\frac{n+1}{n}\to n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{|c_{n+1}|}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$. But I do not see the details.

Comment: Could you give more details please?

Comment: So, what you think that it is missing is how to use the last line of my answer to justify the equality$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n+1]{|c_{n+1}|}\right)^{(n+1)/n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}.$$Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly! This is what I meant

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Let me ask you some questions please: 1) why $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sqrt[n_k+1]{|c_{n_k+1}|}=S$?

Comment: I've edited my answer and I think that it is correct now.

Comment: Does this proof cover the case $S=+\infty$ because $S\in [0,+\infty]$.

Comment: Yes, it does. At no point I assumed that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\in[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna give a more conceptual proof.
The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}z^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}z^{n+1}$ have the same radius of convergence because the latter is the former multiplied by $z$.
The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}z^{n+1}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ have the same radius of convergence by a straightforward calculation.
We conclude the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)c_{n+1}z^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$ have the same radius of convergence.

No need to do any weird computation here ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! But let me ask you a few questions: 1) Can you clarify (or give some details) why radius of convergence remains unchanged when we multiply by $z$? 2) What do you mean by straightforward calculation?

Comment: 1) because the series $f(z)$ converges for $z=z_0$ if and only if the series $zf(z)$ converges for $z=z_0$
2) The calculation of $\limsup$

Answer (score 2):

Let's first consider the case when $R\in (0,\infty)$.

Let $\frac 1R=\limsup |c_n|^\frac 1n$. Choose any $r\gt \frac 1R$.

It follows that for all large $n$, $|c_n|^\frac 1n\lt r$, which gives $|c_{n+1}|^{\frac 1{n+1}}\lt r$ for all large $n$.

Simplifying gives: $$|c_{n+1}|^\frac 1n\lt r^{\frac {n+1}n}=r. r^\frac 1n \text{ for all large $n$ }\implies \limsup |c_{n+1}|^\frac 1n\le r\tag 1$$

---

Note that $x:=\limsup |c_{n+1}|^\frac 1n$ can't be smaller than $\frac 1R$. For if $x\lt \frac 1R$ then choose $y\in (x,\frac 1R)$ and hence by limit superior definition it follows that $|c_{n+1}|^\frac 1n\lt y$ for all large $n$, which is same as saying $|c_{n+1}|^\frac 1{n+1}\lt y^{\frac n{n+1}}$ for all large $n$. It follows that $$\limsup |c_{n+1}|^{\frac 1{n+1}}\le y\implies \frac 1 R\le y$$ which is a contradiction.

---

The following must hold:$$x\ge \frac 1R\tag 2$$

It follows by $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $\limsup |c_n|^\frac 1n=x$.

Particular cases when $R=0$ (with the notion that $1/0:=\infty$) and $R=\infty$ (with the notion that $\frac 1\infty:=0$) can be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful: if $x_n \to a \gt 0$, then $x_n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=x_n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\to a$, as $x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$.

**Addition.**

Let's consider $a_n=x_n^{\frac{1}{n}} = x_n^{\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}} =b_n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$, so $b_n=x_n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$. As is written above and you agreed in comment, if $b_n \to b \gt 0$ have some limit, then same limit will have $a_n$. So, we can say same for positive limit points of $b_n$, which gives, that $a_n$ have same positive limit points with $b_n$.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain why solves my question? In my questuon everything is limsup.

Comment: For limsup of sequence we have subsequence with limit limsup.

Comment: That is true but anyway I do not see how it solves the question? Can you provide a bit more details?

Comment: Wrote addition. Let me note, that it's only fair to wait my comment and down vote in case of dissatisfaction.

Comment: I have to confess that I actually did not downvote your answer.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question and all the answer

Comment: Because my answer had up voted and now is down, I can guess, that this is done by one and same person, while I change nothing in my answer. But, Ok. It's h/is/er right in the end. Are You satisfied now with the detail of my answer or do you need more clarification?

Comment: Please sorry but I am really confused. We need to show that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_{n+1}|}$. How to derive this equality using your answer? I am trying to do it on the paper but I failed.

Comment: $a_n=x_n^{\frac{1}{n}} $ and $b_n=x_n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ have same set of positive limit points, so $\sup$ will be also same.

Comment: You said that there is a subsequence with limit equal to limsup. I thought that you are using this. Sorry can you provide a detailed answer which proves the equality I was looking for? I'd be very grateful for your help!

Comment: $\limsup$ is supremum of limit points of sequence. When sequences have same set of limit points, then their supremum is also same. You disagree ?