# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^{\alpha_n} = x$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was reading the proof of the following equality

$$\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_{n+1}|}$$

in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181981/radius-of-convergence-of-power-series-and-its-formal-derivative). In the first answer, we define

$$a_n:=\sqrt[n]{|c_n|} $$
$$b_n :=\left(a_{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)/n}$$
$$S := \limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$$

then we conclude that there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} = S$$

I understood everything at this point, but then we conclude that

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}(a_{n_k})^{n_k/(n_k-1)}=S
$$

I know that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_k}{n_k-1}=1$, how this limit implies the above limit? I think I have to prove the following:

> Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers which converges to $x$ and let $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers that converges to 1, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}} = x$$

But, how to do this?

Comment: $\alpha_n\log x_n\to1\log x.$

Comment: @AnneBauval and how to solve the case when $x=0$?

Comment: Same (with $\log(0^+)=-\infty$).

Comment: @AnneBauval It does, thanks.